# Groovy Sql WithBatch missing records in DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, groovy, batch-processing

I'm using Groovy Sql.withBatch to process a CSV file and load all the data in my Postgres DB.

Here my method:

```
def processCSV() {
    def logger = Logger.getLogger('groovy.sql')
    logger.level = Level.FINE
    logger.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler(level: Level.FINE))

    def fileName = "file.csv"
    def resource = this.getClass().getResource( '/csv/' + fileName )

    File file = new File(resource.path)

    String year = '2016'

    char separator = ','

    def lines = CSV
            .separator(separator)
            .skipLines(1)
            .quote(CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
            .escape(CSVParser.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER)
            .charset('UTF-8')
            .create()
            .reader(file)
            .readAll()

    def totalLines = lines.size()

    Sql sql = getDatabaseInstance()

    println("Delete existing rows for " + year + " if exists")
    String dQuery = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE year = ?"
    sql.execute(dQuery, [year])

    def statement = 'INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3, coulmn4, year) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'

    println("Total lines in the CSV files: " + totalLines)

    def batches = []

    sql.withBatch(BATCH_SIZE, statement) { ps ->
        lines.each { fields ->
            String coulmn1 = fields[0]
            String coulmn2 = fields[1]
            String column3 = fields[2]
            String column4 = fields[3]

            def params = [column1, coulmn2, column3, column4, year]

            def batch = ['params': params, 'error': false]
            try {
                ps.addBatch(params)
            }
            catch (all) {
                batch['error'] = true
                throw all
            }

            batches << batch
        }
    }

    def recordsAddedInDB = sql.firstRow("SELECT count(*) FROM " + tableName + " WHERE year = ?", year)[0]

    sql.close()

    println("")
    println("Processed lines: " + line)
    println("Batches: " + batches.size())
    println("Batches in error: " + batches.findAll{ it.error }.size())
    println("Record in DB for " + year + ": " + recordsAddedInDB)
}
```

The lines in the CSV files (exclusing the header line) are 23758.
The output of this method is the following:

```
Delete existing rows for 2016 if exists
Total lines in the CSV files: 23758
Processed lines: 23758
Batches: 23758
Batches in error: 0
Record in DB for 2016 year: 23580
```

If I enable the logging, with a BATCH_SIZE of 500, I can see:

- 47 times, the sentence "Successfully executed batch with 500 command(s)"
- 1 time the sentence "Successfully executed batch with 258 command(s)"

Which means 23758 insert statement have been processed.

Anybody has any idea why the number of rows in the database are less that the processed ones?

Comment: Just for exatra forensics: might be worth looking at the return value from sql.withBatch, eg `def counts = sql.withBatch { }.sum()`. Might also be useful to add a `ps.executeBatch()` directly after the ps.addBatch to see what you get.

Comment: sql.withBatch { }.sum() returns 23580...which is the same number of records I have in the database. If I add the ps.executeBatch(), then each insert statement is executed alone, sql.withBatch { }.sum() returns 0 and in the database I still have the same number of records.

Comment: Any chance you have duplicate values for the id columns in your indata? i.e. you might be inserting identical lines which would overwrite each other in the database.

Comment: The INSERT statement does not include the ID which is automatically incremented. This should ensure this scenario should not happen, am I right?

Comment: Yes, assuming the autoincrement values are working as they should that should remove that possibility.

Comment: I've also check with Excel the CSV file and no duplicates are present. Since I'm using the batches variable to keep track of all the params for every insert statement, I've also checked if inside there are duplicates, but also there no duplicates are present.

Comment: I've also tried to add the ID manually and add it to the statement, but I'm still having the same numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The INSERT statement has a subquery, when the subquery doesn't return a value, the INSERT statement is ignored.